# Change Developer name in Google play store doesn't update

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I have two old apps in the Google Play. The apps name are fine but I'm trying to update the developer name for those two apps (the text below the app name).

I went to **https://play.google.com/apps/publish -> "Settings" -> "Account Details"** then I updated the **"Developer Name"** property and then save the changes. I waited half a day but my apps developer name still remain unchanged. I tried with other field such as the website and it does the same thing.

Do I need to re-publish the applications? I don't know what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok nevermind, I just had to wait about 12 hours to be updated by Google Play. Please be aware that is not an immediate change.

Comment: I'm waiting for the past 3 days now. Still, my new name hasn't changed.

Answer (score 7):

According to the Google Play Console, developer name changes are not immediate. It is said that the update can take up to 7 days. [Here is a screenshot of the message they display right after there is an attempt to update the developer name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cug8A.png)

Comment: https://play.google.com/apps/publish -> "Settings" -> "Account Details" then I updated the "Developer Name" property. The developer name is displayed to users under your application name. Changes to the developer name will be reviewed by Google and can take up to seven days.